# How to programmatically set accessibilityLabel on UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, uiaccessibility

I am attempting to programmatically set the accessibility label and value for a UILabel (the one titled 'Mega Title!') in my UIViewController.  Here's my viewDidLoad...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // seems you can only set value on UILabel
    self.powLabel.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.powLabel.accessibilityLabel = @"lbl label";    // sets value ???
    self.powLabel.accessibilityValue = @"lbl value";    // this doesn't work.

    // you can set title and value on UIView
    self.powView.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.powView.accessibilityLabel = @"view label";    // sets title
    self.powView.accessibilityValue = @"view value";    // sets value


    // you can set title and value on UIButton
    self.powButton.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.powButton.accessibilityLabel = @"btn label";    // sets title
    self.powButton.accessibilityValue = @"btn value";    // this value   
}
```

The accessibility title/value gets set correctly in the UIView and UIButton controls...however only the accessibility value gets set on the UILabel control.  Here's a screenshot of what the Accessibility Inspector shows...

[image]

How do you setup a UILabel so that accessibilityLabel actually has a value?

Comment: What do you want to achieve from accessibility value?

Comment: I need to have blind users know A-what the label is titled and B-what the value of the label is.

Comment: Try accessibilityHint

Comment: Yessir - have already tried that and it doesn't seem to affect either the accessibilityLabel or accessibilityValue values.

Answer (score 0):

UILabel will have the text set using `.text` on it as accessibilityLabel, depending on what you want to do I think it's better to use `accessibilityIdentifier` to identify UI elements and leave the default value.

Comment: I've attempted to also set the accessibilityIdentifier...which doesn't seem to set either the label or the value for any of the above (UILabel, UIView, UIButton) controls.

Answer (score 0):

When inspecting accessibility of a view inside an app on the simulator you need to be sure to select the simulator as the current context instead of your computer. Clicking the current selection in the top left reveals a dropdown.

[image: Accessibility Inspector Example]